# Find the projection in the subspacing where the vector $X = (1,3,-1,3)$ originates from the vectors $A_1 (1, -1,1,1), A_2 (5,1,-3,3).$

Tags: operator-theory

> How can I find the projection in the subspacing where the vector $X = (1,3,-1,3)$ originates from the vectors $A_1 (1, -1,1,1), A_2 (5,1,-3,3).$

I have not found an example of this problem in my book. That's why I can not solve it. I'm stuck.

Comment: what is the subsapace?

Comment: check $X = (1,3-1,3)$ maybe $X = (1,3,-1,3)$

Comment: @gimusi I translate in Google translate. Is question not clear?

Comment: @gimusi I fixed Thank you.

Comment: what vector you need to project and in which subspace?

Comment: are you looking for the projection of X onto span(A1,A2) or the projection of A1,A2 onto X? it is not clear

Comment: @gimusi you are right, maybe

Comment: @gimusi I edited. (new translate)

Comment: there is also a typo here $A_2 (5,1,-3,3)$

Comment: @gimusi again I fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Recall that the projection matrix $P$ onto the subspace $span(A_1,A_2)$ is given by

$$P=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$$

where $A=[A_1\quad A_2]$.

Comment: (+1) Would you like to write more, please :(

Comment: @Beginner You have all what you need to proceed, construct matrix A and then matrix P, then the projection of X onto span(A_1,A_2) is given by $X_A=PX$.

Comment: @Beginner You are welcome! Bye